# geom_density() by day of the week in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to create a density plot for the occurrences by days of the week.

I have the following data:

```
         dateDelivered       day
5  2015-07-13 14:57:34    Monday
11 2015-07-22 16:50:11 Wednesday
12 2015-07-27 12:08:13    Monday
13 2015-07-28 10:30:44   Tuesday
14 2015-07-28 12:42:58   Tuesday
```

However, with the following ggplot code, I get the following output:

```
ggplot(df_delivered, aes(x = day))+ 
  geom_density(aes(fill=day))
```

The image of the output can be found here:

[image]

Ideally, I would like a single line showing the density of each day.

Comment: I'm not sure how a "density plot" makes any sense here. A density of what for each day? You could, for example, plot the density of the time of day for each day of the week (maybe Mondays are always in the morning, Wednesdays are always late etc) but you've not even included the dateDelivered variable in your code.... What did you expect?

Comment: you could make a simple histogram : `ggplot(df_delivered, aes(x = day)) + geom_bar()`, or if it must be a line, change to `+ geom_freqpoly()`

Comment: I was expecting to have a line to show how the number of occurrences changes over the course of the week.

Comment: I did a histogram as well, but I was hoping to create a plot with a line to show a change over time. However since days are discrete, a density plot may not be the best option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that `geom_density(...)` wants a continuous x-axis, and you're providing a factor. Here's a way to do more or less what you're asking. This is somewhat similar to the other answer.

```
# create sample dataset - you have this already
set.seed(1)   # for reproducibility
dow <- c("M","T","W","Th","F")
df <- data.frame(x=sample(dow,100, replace=TRUE,p=c(.2,.4,.2,.1,.1)))
df$x <- with(df,factor(x, levels=dow))   # need this to get days in the correct order

# you start here...
ggplot(df, aes(x=as.numeric(x))) + 
  geom_histogram(aes(y=..density..),binwidth=1, fill="lightgreen", color="grey70", origin=0.5)+
  stat_density(color="red", geom="line")+
  scale_x_continuous(name="",labels=dow, breaks=seq_along(dow))
```

[image]

Comment: This was a brilliant explanation. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to do it, with a little wrangling.

First you need to convert your time to POSIXct, if it is not already:

```
df_delivered$date2 <- as.POSIXct(df_delivered$dateDelivered, format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

Next, turn the day column into a factor, so we can get the number of days passed each week:

```
df_delivered$day <- factor(df_delivered$day, levels = c("Sunday", "Monday", 
                                   "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"))
```

Now we need to get the amount of time passed in each day:

```
df_delivered$date3 <- as.numeric(df_delivered$date2 - trunc(df_delivered$date2, "days"))/60
```

Now we can plot, using our a axis as 24* the number of days, plus the date column:

```
ggplot(df_delivered, aes(x = date3+as.numeric(day)*24)) +
    geom_density()
```

EDIT: from a simulated dataset, with time already as POSIXct.
Data, named as df_delivered:

```
structure(list(dateDelivered = structure(c(1325420712.07391, 
1325473818.87468, 1325944988.29881, 1326644837.14753, 1327078496.72151, 
1327173445.32841, 1328170080.73442, 1330948998.35264, 1332327962.56186, 
1332768069.2447, 1333181987.1911, 1335463412.38292, 1336150093.37186, 
1336729162.94389, 1336794193.70351, 1336815576.06732, 1336890600.1805, 
1336933569.03092, 1337348143.61397, 1337616505.99632, 1337639497.61884, 
1338600812.52401, 1338605366.09276, 1338723437.09295, 1339189548.67689, 
1339517147.2495, 1339932397.01648, 1340107202.65251, 1340330642.50151, 
1341405354.71406, 1341418497.24939, 1344275327.79584, 1344286095.22275, 
1344613247.17759, 1348160598.15293, 1348759049.56039, 1348961725.19995, 
1349065123.77902, 1349191950.54645, 1349200558.14843, 1350922752.47161, 
1351430185.1209, 1351531759.2165, 1351534610.79749, 1351964975.69713, 
1352534323.88355, 1353403252.48848, 1353737961.90685, 1354897718.11477, 
1355562841.50268), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt")), day = structure(c(4L, 
4L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 5L, 2L, 7L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 
4L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 6L, 4L, 6L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 6L, 6L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 6L, 3L, 1L, 
3L), .Label = c("Friday", "Monday", "Saturday", "Sunday", "Thursday", 
"Tuesday", "Wednesday"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("dateDelivered", 
"day"), row.names = c(NA, -50L), class = "data.frame")
```

Process and plot:

```
df_delivered$day <- factor(df_delivered$day, levels = c("Sunday", "Monday", 
                                                        "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"))
df_delivered$date3 <- as.numeric(df_delivered$dateDelivered - trunc(df_delivered$dateDelivered, "days"))/60
ggplot(df_delivered, aes(x=date3+as.numeric(day)*24)) +geom_density()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: It works, depending on OPs input - ill stick up a simulated dataset in a sec